# mod_rewrite for specific domains in a mappings file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mappings

I have a bunch of domains that I want to go to one domain but various parts of that domain.

```
# this is what I currently have
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.?foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ ${domainmappings:www.foo.com} [L,R=301]

# rewrite map file
www.foo.com www.domain.com/domain/foo.com.php
www.bar.com www.domain.com/domain/bar.com.php
www.baz.com www.domain.com/other/baz.php.foo
```

The problem is that I don't want to have to have each domain be part of the RewriteCond. I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but that will do it for EVERY domain. I only want the domains that are in the mappings file to redirect, and then continue on to other rewrites if it doesn't match any domains in the mappings file.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  What you have to do is use the pipe operator on the map so that you have a catch-all.

```
RewriteCond ${domainmappings:%{HTTP_HOST}|NOTFOUND}    ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %1  !^NOTFOUND$
RewriteRule ^.*$ ${domainmappings:%1} [L,R=301]
```

The second condition will not match if the host is not in the list.  You still have to deal with the www prefix, and the case matching, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm close as I figured out the the case matching, but unable to figure out the www prefix. If I use the first one below, it works without www. If I use the second one, it works with the www. If I use BOTH - neither work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)$ [NC] # works for without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] # works with www
RewriteCond ${domainmappings:%1|NOTFOUND} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^NOTFOUND$
RewriteRule ^.*$ ${domainmappings:%1} [L,R=301]
```

Any ideas?